# Keep flyout menu open when hover over parent or menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

I've been through quite a few questions on here trying to figure out the best way to do this but can't make them work with my code. I just want the flyout menu to stay put while the mouse is on it after becoming visible when the main menu item element is hovered. Note that the sub-menus are *not* children of the main menu item. They sit alongside them.

Here's my current script:
I need the flyover menu to stay shown until the user moves their mouse off either the menu item itself (unless moving onto the flyover) or off the flyover.

```
$('.menuItem').mouseover(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = item.substring(item.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var findFlyout = '#acFly_' + id;
    $(findFlyout).show();
})

$('.menuItem').mouseleave(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = item.substring(item.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var findFlyout = '#acFly_' + id;
    $(findFlyout).hide();
})
```

You can see the live page here: http://205.134.239.12/~artscr6/artscrush/

Answer (score 0):

The html for the menu is incorrect, as the ul tag can contain only li tags (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). You should add the fly-out divs inside the li items. Once you fix this, the hover effect will also work.

Comment: Good call. I've updated the HTML to it's not using true ul/li elements anymore (just divs with classes). I can't put the flyover elements inside the parent elements because I need the flyover box to "break out" of the parent element so it can expand across the page, and the parent element has to be relatively positioned because of another child element that relies on its boundaries for absolute positioning. That was a mouth full to type....

Answer (score 0):

You need `mouseover` and not `hover`.

---

`Hover` handles both `mouseover`, which you want, but ALSO `mouseout`, which you don't. As soon as you move your mouse off the link, your flyover hides.

`Mouseover` will show the flyover when your mouse hits the link and won't do any hiding.

NOTE: You will still need some code to hide the flyover. Try this first and see how it works.

---

Hover:
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Mouseover:
https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Adding some code:

Include [Outside Events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/)

```
$('.menuItem').mouseover(function() {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = item.substring(item.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var $findFlyout = $('#acFly_' + id);
    // remove previous bound clickoutside
    $('.flyMenu').unbind('clickoutside');
    // close flyout when clicked outside
    $findFlyout.on('clickoutside', function() {
      $findFlyout.unbind('clickoutside').hide();
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that make sense. I've updated the code in my question with what I have now. It is working to show/hide the flyout, but I also need to the flyout to stay shown while the user is hover over the menu item or the flyout. How do I detect what's being hovered to determine when to hide/show? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please fix the example page. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, it should be back in shape now, I was working on it before.

Comment: What you did was duplicate the original hover behavior. You need to remove the mouseleave (btw: mouseout is more often used). Now the flyover doesn't close. I usually use Ben Alman's Outside Events for this. It will fire an event whenever you click outside the menu.  $(findFlyout).on('clickoutside', function() { $(findFlyout).unbind('clickoutside').hide(); });